# Conversion of GRIB and NetCDF to my database

Tags: conversion, database, csv, grid

I have downloaded "High Resolution Initial Conditions" climate forecast data for one day. It was a .tar.gz file so I extracted it in my local directory and I get the files as shown in the image below:

[image]

I think that the files without an extension are GRIB data (because the first word in them is "GRIB"). I want to get the data from the big files (GRIB and NetCDF formats containing climate data like temperature and pressure in grid) to my database, but they are a binary format.

Can you recommend an easy way to retrieve the data from these files? I can't get any information about handling their datasets on their website.

Converting these files to .csv format would be nice, but I can't find any working program to convert the GRIB files.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [wgrib2](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2/) utility to either extract the data at a chosen time or lat/lon location, or to convert to Netcdf.